# Azure : Can not install 3rd party setup due to access denied on registry

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I am trying to install a 3rd party exe (for [EDIdEv](http://www.edidev.com/index.html)) on azure cloud server.
Installation starts but its not completed.

I have successfully installed it on my local machine.

I have checked installation log on server. it fives following error:
FAILURE: Failed to open registry key 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall'. RegOpenKeyEx failed. Access is denied. GetLastError(5)

What can I do in this case.

I am using KUDU to install on server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Apps are not full-access VMs; they are sandboxed, so you will not be able to install software that makes such modifications (e.g. registry).

You'll need to install to a Virtual Machine (or web/worker role cloud service), in this case, to host this particular app.

Comment: So can I do the installation with Cloud services?

Comment: Yes, as I already stated (though I've never installed that particular bit of software - you'll need to try it out for yourself). Plenty of documentation available on installing software in cloud services.

Comment: By the way, if you're not doing something tremendously complex with that bit of software you may get away with using Logic Apps instead - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-x12